# Array removed after function?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am making a script that goes into all servers we're hosting and gets all members of a specific group and the domain name, and then exports it to a file. I'm saving the users and the domain names into two arrays AA (user array) and DA (domain array) AA stands for användararray, and "användare" is users in swedish so it makes sense to me.

I noticed that the export step didn't work, no users or domain names were exported, so I tried to print them in the function. But it doesn't print anything, so I tried to print it in a different location (didn't work). After some experimenting I came to the conlusion that the only place the arrays actually contains any information is inside the foreach loop where I save the users that I find??!

Here is the code

```
unction GetData([int]$p) {

Write-Host("B") 

for ($row = 1; $row -le $UsernamesArray.Length; $row++) 
{

    if($CloudArray[$row] -eq 1)
    {

        .

        $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString 
        $PasswordsArray[$row].ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
        $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UsernamesArray[$row], $secstr



        $output = Invoke-Command -computername $AddressArray[$row] -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {

            Import-Module Activedirectory                

            foreach ($Anvandare in (Get-ADGroupMember fjärrskrivbordsanvändare)) 
            {

                $AA = @($Anvandare.Name) 
                $DA = gc env:UserDomain
                #$DA + ";" + $Anvandare.Name
                $DA + ";" + $AA
            }
        }
    $output
    }
}
$DA
$AA
}

function Export {

Write-Host("C")


$filsökväg = "C:\Users\322sien\Desktop\Coolkids.csv"
$ColForetag = "Företag"
$ColAnvandare = "Användare"
$Emptyline = "`n"
$delimiter = ";"

for ($p = 1; $p -le $DomainArray.Length; $p++) {


    $ColForetag + $delimiter + $ColAnvandare | Out-File $filsökväg




    $DA + $delimiter + $AA | Out-File $filsökväg -Append

    }
}

ReadInfo
GetData
Export
```

Can anyone help me with this? I've sat down with this all day and i cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables $DA and $AA are bound to GetData function, so they live only there. You could make them available inside your script by changing it's **scope**.

Change this:

```
            $AA = @($Anvandare.Name) 
            $DA = gc env:UserDomain
```

To this:

```
            $script:AA = @($Anvandare.Name) 
            $script:DA = gc env:UserDomain
```

So they will now be available for other functions inside the script.

Also I found the ways to improve your script, hope you can see the logic:

```
function GetData([int]$p) {

Write-Host("B") 

    for ($row = 1; $row -le $UsernamesArray.Length; $row++) 
    {

        if($CloudArray[$row] -eq 1)
        {

            .

            $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString 
            $PasswordsArray[$row].ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
            $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UsernamesArray[$row], $secstr



            [array]$output = Invoke-Command -computername $AddressArray[$row] -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {

                Import-Module Activedirectory  
                $array = @()            
                foreach ($Anvandare in (Get-ADGroupMember fjärrskrivbordsanvändare)) 
                {
                    $object = New-Object PSObject
                    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AA -Value @($Anvandare.Name) 
                    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DA -Value (gc env:UserDomain)
                    $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Something -Value $DA + ";" + $AA
                    $array += $object
                }
                Write-Output $array
            }
        Write-Output $output
        }
    }
}
```

Your function will now output some data.

Comment: How should I call on the arrays? Like `$AA` or `$script:AA` @AgentK I tried both ways and nothing happens...

Comment: Oh and btw. I can only print the values inside the FOREACH loop, not even in the same function outside of the loop. If we could start a chat to discuss this further that would be great

Comment: Sorry I can't being online every minute. Didn't mean to hurt anyone. Anyway you should use something like PSObject to output valid data. I will fix the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm just tired of people answering and not giving a shit about further problems. +rep to you do cared

Comment: Im a bit new to powershell so please explain why you put `[array]` before `$output` and why you do write-output. How can I now use the array to export the data into a csv file supposed to looking like this http://imgur.com/VOhdTNc The export function that exports is in my question